# to get one dropdownlist dependent on another php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Currently I have questions which are displayed according to chapters as follows:

[image]

here is the code for the above image to show chapters

```
<select style="width:100%; " name="chapter_id_search" id="chapter_id_search" class="form-control">
<option value="" > --- Select Chapter --- </option>
 <?php 
    $coneccion = new Conexion();
    $query = "SELECT `Chapter_ID`, `Chapter_Name`, `Chapter_Description` FROM `chapter_master` order by chapter_sequence";
    $sql = mysql_query($query)or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $chapter_id  = $_SESSION["chapterid"];
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        if($chapter_id == $row['Chapter_ID'])
        {
            echo("<option value = '" . $row['Chapter_ID'] . "' selected>" . $row['Chapter_Name'] . "</option>");
        }
        else
        {
        echo("<option value = '" . $row['Chapter_ID'] . "'>" . $row['Chapter_Name'] . "</option>");
        }                       
    }
 ?>
</select>
```

On click of the table and edit opens as follows where i have loaded a page ad set chapter id as 
`$chapter_id  =$view->questions->getChapter_ID();`

[image]

Also i can add a new question as follows after clicking the new question on screen 1.

[image]

I need to add subeject to the filter now

I added the subject code as follows

```
 <select style="width:40%; float:left; margin-left: 5%; " name="subject_id_search" id="subject_id_search" class="form-control" >
 <option value="" > --- Select Subject --- </option>
  <?php 
    $coneccion = new Conexion();
    $query = "SELECT `Subject_ID`, `Subject_Name`  FROM `subject_master` order by Subject_ID";
    $sql = mysql_query($query)or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $subject_id = $_SESSION[subject_id_session_search];

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        if( $subject_id == $row['Subject_ID'] )
        {
        echo("<option value = '" . $row['Subject_ID'] . "' selected>" . $row['Subject_Name'] . "</option>");
        }

        else
        {
        echo("<option value = '" . $row['Subject_ID'] . "' >" . $row['Subject_Name'] . "</option>");
        }
    }

  ?>
 </select>
```

and on its on change added a different php page to show chapters in another dropdownlist

```
 $("#subject_id_search").change(function(){ 
        var params={};
        params.subject_id=$('#subject_id_search').val();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search/chapter_search_by_subject_id.php",
            //data:'subject_id ='+ $('#subject_id_search').val(),

              data:params,
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
                $("#chapter_id_search").html(data);
            }
            });
        });
```

this works as follows [image]

The problem is that

1 ) I have called another php page to load the chapters and the selected chapter is not been seen here.

2 ) I need to add the subjects to the edit and add screen also.
Iam not getting how to add the subjects there as have currently taken directly the chapters as shown above as i need to call the function to get the chapter id selected if the case is edit.
The problem is that it does not call the method

```
$chapter_id  =$view->questions->getChapter_ID();
```

3) Is that a good option to write different pages to call the chapters as i also have many other pages in my app where i have subject and chapter filter.
I cannot create one single page and call as I have to maintained different sessions also i need to call the getchapterid() function which are different for different pages.

Please help